# How to update Json string in SQL

Tags: sql, json

I have this JSON string:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "TGName",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "ISD",
    "Value": "{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"row\":{\"Category\":\"Epr Oxygen\",\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}}}"
  }
]
```

In this JSON, value of "Category" key needs to update from "Epr Oxygen" to "Damper".

I have written this query to fetch the value = Epr Oxygen from above JSON and I got the value:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTempAVI (input nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @inputWiCate nvarchar(max)='[
  {
    "Name": "TGName",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "ISD",
    "Value": "{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"row\":{\"Category\":\"Epr Oxygen\",\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}}}"
  }
]'

INSERT INTO SomeTempAVI 
    SELECT VALUE 
    FROM OPENJSON (@inputWiCate)
    WITH (Name nvarchar(100), Value nvarchar(max))  
    WHERE name = 'ISD'

DECLARE @inputValue nvarchar(max)

SELECT @inputValue = Category 
FROM OPENJSON ((SELECT TOP 1 input FROM SomeTempAVI))
     WITH (SIData NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.SIData)
            WITH (row NVARCHAR(MAX)  AS JSON) b  
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(b.row) 
            WITH (Category NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Category') c 

PRINT @inputValue

DROP TABLE SomeTempAVI
```

But I didn't get how to update that value to "damper".

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for you. You need to rebuild the JSON array again using `FOR JSON`, using either the original `Value` properties, or a modified `Value`, depending on your conditions.

The inner object is double-encoded unfortunately, which complicates things. For some reason, SQL Server is not re-encoding it correctly. You may want to investigate why it's double-encoded in the first place.

Note that a temp table is unnnecessary

```sql
DECLARE @inputWiCate nvarchar(max)='[
  {
    "Name": "TGName",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "ISD",
    "Value": "{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"row\":{\"Category\":\"Epr Oxygen\",\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}}}"
  }
]'

SELECT
  j1.Name,
  Value = CASE WHEN j1.Name = 'ISD'
       THEN JSON_MODIFY(j1.value, '$.SIData.row.Category', 'Damper')
       ELSE j1.Value
       END
FROM OPENJSON (@inputWiCate)
  WITH (
    Name nvarchar(100),
    Value nvarchar(max)
  ) j1
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zrd2Tny7)

If the `Value` is not double-encoded then change the above code like this

```sql
FROM OPENJSON (@inputWiCate)
  WITH (
    Name nvarchar(100),
    Value nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) j1
```